# Wordpress generated page with values from url

Tags: wordpress, url, plugins, categories, taxonomy

I'm currently trying to build a wordpress product catalog with a custom taxonomy.
I'd like to have browseable multi-level category system, so if I click the Catalog menu, it would show all the top parent categories, and if I click on one of these categories, instead of showing me the posts in that particular category, I want it to list all it's subcategories.

For this I'm using two slightly modified plugins currently:

Multi column taxonomy list, and taxonomy images.

My approach would be to have the taxonomy lister display custom links linke www.xyz.com/wp/product?cat=doors

and the product page would process the $_GET data cat and forward it to the shortcode somehow so it would be [mctl taxonomy='productcategories' parent='$_GET['parentid']']
.

So for the TLDR: How can I pass variables from the URL to the shortcode, or to the plugin.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. I just had to edit the plugins php and use the $_GET[''] stuff there.